# Storing a set of serialized protobuf objects

Tags: c++, serialization, protocol-buffers, separator

I'm using `SerializeToString` on my Protobuf objects, and then store the string in a DB.

However, sometimes I have an array of such objects. I would like to store the whole serialized array, and for that I need some separator string between the serialized strings.

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial) I've seen, the string is just a byte array, and so I got nothing promised to me regarding its content.

What would be the best approach here?

I don't know the length of the array because objects may be appended to it as we go, and I want it stored in DB throughout the entire process.

Comment: How about prefixing the string stream with length information ?

Comment: I could prefix a sizeof(int) in front of each string. Sounds like it should work. I'll try and post results if will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose, your protobuf `message` looks like this:

```
message Object
{
  ... = 1;
  ... = 2;
  ... = 3;
}
```

Then in the same file introduce 1 more `message` which is a collection of these `Object`s.

```
message Objects
{
  repeated Object array = 1;
}
```

Hence, when you have many elements, you may simply use the `Objects` and use `SerializeAsString()` on `Objects` itself. That will save your efforts of serializing individual `Object` separately and putting your own handmade delimiter. You can serialize all the `Object`s using single instance of `Objects`.
With this approach you are **delegating all parsing & serializing work also to Protobuf library**. I use this in my project and it works like a charm.

Additionally, judicious use of `Objects` will also avoid making extra copies of `Object`. You can add items to that and access using indexing. The `repeated` fields of protobufs are C++11 compliant, hence you may use it with iterators or enhanced `for` loop as well.

---

Important to note that, when you are storing the output of the `Objects::SerializeAsString()` into a file, you should first input the length of that `string` followed by the actual serialized string. While reading, you can read the length first followed by the total bytes. For ease of use, I have extended the `std::fstream` and overloaded the below methods:

```
struct fstreamEncoded : std::fstream
{
    // other methods
    void  // returns `void` to avoid multiple `<<` in a single line
    operator<< (const string& content)
    {  // below casting would avoid recursive calling of this method
       // adding `length() + 1` to include the protobuf's last character as well
      static_cast<std::fstream&>(*this) << (content.length() + 1) << "\n" << content << std::endl;
    }

    string
    getline ()
    {
      char length_[20] = {};
      std::istream::getline(length_, sizeof(length_) - 1);
      if(*length_ == 0)
        return "";

      const size_t length = std::atol(length_);  // length of encoded input
      string content(length, 0);  // resize the `string`
      read(&content[0], length);  // member of `class istream`
      return content;
    }
}
```

Above is the just an illustration. You may follow according to your project needs.

Comment: While this is a beautiful solution, it would be wasteful in terms of appending serialized data to one another. I would have to deserialize, append and re-serialize

Comment: @Mugen, there is no waste of resources unless you decide to keep `Object`s and `Objects` separate. Moreover, there is no "appending serialized data", but simply "appending data". Afterwards you can serialize only when storing in file or passing to some other realm. Similarly deserialize. If you find any waste of resource, then I would suggest to update here in comment or your Q with the relevant example, so that I can clear your doubts.

Comment: @Mugen Actually, due to the details of the protobuf format, if you concatenate two instances of `Objects` (as defined above), it is exactly equivalent to concatenating the `array` repeated field into a single instance and serializing that. So you don't have to deserialize to append!

Comment: @KentonVarda, probably you meant the concatenation of `Object`s and not `Objects`. Yes it's correct. In fact manually serializing each `Object` and then separating into a file with user defined delimiter is quite cumbersome compared to built-in protobuf capability of serializing all of them in form of single `Objects` instance. Not sure, where OP is finding it difficult.

Comment: @KentonVarda that's a useful piece of info, thanks. With that I can use this solution. Better add it to the answer.

Comment: @Mugen, updated. Also note that (as shown in `operator<<`), we have to add `length + 1` bytes of the encoded protobuf string as a length. This `length + 1` will be finally used while reading from file. Later that can be deserialized.

Comment: @iammilind No, I meant `Objects`. The point is, if you have a message that just contains a repeated field, then concatenating two serialized forms of the message is exactly equivalent to parsing each, concatenating the repeated field, then serializing again. Hence, it's possible for @Mugen to append new values to his list without deserializing the previous ones.

Comment: @KentonVarda, just saw your profile & nice to know that you are associated with "google protobuf". In this same Q, I have 1 side query. Plz see if you can help. Suppose in above example of `Object` and `Objects`, we have multiple `Object` already stored in a serialized form in a file. Now to construct a single instance of `Objects`, we will have to de-serialize every instance of `Object` and add to `Objects` and then again serialize it. Is there any way by which we can leverage the already serialized string of `Object` into composing `Objects`? Kindly inform me, if the Q was not clear. Thanks!

Comment: @iammilind: A sub-message is encoded exactly the same as a `bytes` field where the bytes are the serialized sub-message. So, you can define `message ObjectsRaw { repeated bytes array = 1; }` and fill `array` with serialized `Object`s, without decoding each one. The resulting message will be binary-compatible with `Objects`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't guarantee that your separator would be unique to the contents of the serialized data, then I would add a size item at the start of each object indicating how long the following string is.